# A guide to moving from Visual Studio to Eclipse

Tags: visual-studio, eclipse

Is there guide out there that will help me, A .Net developer whose been using Visual studio for some time, get to grips with Eclipse?

Even just a quick guide to eclipse.

Has anyone else made the transition, and if so how did you cope. Any Tips?

Comment: you will use eclipse to write java?

Comment: Yes, I'm now required to write some code in java.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure if it will help you, but Eric Sink ran a nice four part series some time ago on his move from VS to Eclipse:

[From C# to Java - Part 1](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/java_eclipse_1.html)

[From C# to Java - Part 2](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/java_eclipse_2.html)

[From C# to Java - Part 3](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/java_eclipse_3.html)

[From C# to Java - Part 4](http://www.ericsink.com/entries/java_eclipse_4.html)

Comment: I remember reading some of that a while ago. I'll have a look at it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using Vista or XP? If Vista, one tip I will give you is run Eclipse in XP compatibility mode. If you are using XP, this tip can be ignored as it doesn't affect you.

If you do use Vista, take a read of [item 2 - Automatic scrolling - in this blog post I wrote](http://www.davidarno.org/2008/07/14/five-vista-annoyances-and-how-to-work-around-them/).

Comment: Thanks for the info, I'm using Xp so it doesn't apply to me. But it might help somone else.

Why is it that it works better in XP compatibility mode?

Comment: Vista introduced a feature called "automatic scrolling" that tries to inteligently scroll trees left/ right as one scrolls up and down. In Eclipse, this feature makes the debug tree for example near unusable. The only way to disable the scrolling is to run Eclipse in XP mode.

Answer (score 0):

There is a DZone Refcardz [Getting Started with Eclipse](http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/getting-started-eclipse) (free registration required)